# How to remove "time" from "date and time" in a row in ms excel and format the date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following column in my MS Excel sheet:

```
7/18/2017 10:41
No Gerrit
7/19/2017 7:45
8/9/2017 12:20
7/19/2017 8:29
8/9/2017 12:23
7/20/2017 10:33
8/3/2017 9:14
9/28/2017 10:33
8/3/2017 9:24
8/3/2017 9:29
8/7/2017 14:10
8/18/2017 8:12
8/16/2017 10:22
Aug 16, 2017 2:08 PM
```

I want to make a formula which will remove time and only keep date, And Also I want to make all dates in same format. ( last date format is different).

I will be really grateful for any help , thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far, and what problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Is the last **format** different or is it text rather than a date?

Comment: @Olly, actually i try to remove last 8 character , but some how it didnt worked , I think dates are not the string , I was looking for some option in kutools also but didnt find any.

Comment: @Enigmativity , yes last format is different , i am looking for that how can i make date format same through out the sheet.

Comment: In Excel, dates are integer numbers, and the hours are decimal parts. Just round down every date to make it only a date

Comment: @pankajkushwaha - If it is merely a format then just format the cell the way you like it. To get rid of time it is just `=INT(<cell_reference>)`.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns : I am sorry but I didn't get what does round down mean , and how to do it ? I am new in excel actually.

Comment: Check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rounddown-function-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: @Enigmativity yes your suggestion is working for removing the date , thanks for it :) any suggestion regarding date format ? I didn't get actually what you told about formatting the date , ( regarding same date format throughout the column).

Comment: @pankajkushwaha - Just use the format painter to copy the format from one of the cells where the date format is right to the last cell where the format isn't right.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Yes its working for removing the time :) , thanks for it , is there any way to make date in same format.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I tried format painter to convert from Aug 16, 2017 to 8/16/2017 , but its not working.

Comment: @pankajkushwaha - Then it is test, right? And not a formatting problem?

Comment: @Enigmativity: I am not sure , I think excel is not recognizing Aug 16, 2017 as a date.

Comment: @pankajkushwaha - Sorry, I meant "text", not "test". If that's the case you'll need to break it apart using `LEFT`, `MID`, `RIGHT`, and `LEN` functions and then convert it to a value using `VALUE`.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Now that you have the dates only, just change the format in the cell. Check https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the worksheet and column/range references then run this short sub procedure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
    With Worksheets(8).Columns(1)
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 3), Array(10, 9))
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , Actually I am new in MS Excel , how to apply this formula.